# Nuxt Typescript tsconfig types not working

Tags: typescript, types, nuxt.js, tsconfig

Trying to migrate Nuxt project from JS to TS. Working in VS Code with Vetur plugin enabled.

Project works well, but I can't setup global variables hionts with tsconfig.json types field.

So here is tsconfig.json file:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "esnext.asynciterable",
      "dom"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
      "@nuxtjs/toast",
      "@nuxtjs/i18n",
      "vue-js-modal",
      "vue-meta",
      "vue-router",
      "nuxt-i18n"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".nuxt",
    "dist"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.vue",
    "vue-shim.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and here is component:

```
<script lang='ts'>
import { Zlaggable } from '@/types/zlaggables/Zlaggable'
import { Component, mixins } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import UtilMixin from '@/assets/ts/UtilMixin'

@Component({
  name: 'ZlaggableHeaderCopyComponent'
})
export default class ZlaggableHeaderCopy extends mixins(UtilMixin) {
  mounted() : void {
    this.$toast.success("jj")
  }
  ...
```

[image]

Instead of methods and property suggestions on $toast I have an error like on the image. The $toast actually works, but the declaration of types in tsconfig.json just do nothing or I did some setup mistake